# How do I implement print functionality using FullCalendar plugin?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using the fullcalendar as a demo. how do I implement print functionality ?
I found a file 'fullcalendar.print.css' in FullCalendar package, what's that use for?

If a have a button "Print" ,what will I do when clicking the button?
Any help will be thankful!

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a bit of an old question but figured I would answer anyway.

include the file the way it tells you for example:

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.print.css " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

I will then setup my button as follows:

```
<button class="printBtn hidden-print">Print</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.printBtn').on('click', function (){
    window.print();
  });
</script>
```

That way your button is hidden from the print screen and when you click the button it pops up a print screen for you.

The hidden-print is a class provided by Bootstrap if you are not using bootstrap you could use something such as the following in a style sheet:

```
@media print {
  .visible-print  { display: inherit !important; }
  .hidden-print   { display: none !important; }
}
```

As far as Using the fullcalendar.print.css?  It gets applied when your `media == print` as per your `<link>`

Answer (score 4):

you could use the solution used in the below link for primefaces schedule (same as full calendar).
http://eves4code.blogspot.in/2014/12/to-print-primefaces-schedule.html

This example opens the print preview of a calendar in a new tab.

Extract from the above link is is

This example is implemented for primefaces schedule component which uses fullcalendar in the backend

The printScheduleArea is div tag enclosing the primefaces schedule.

In your XHTML, add a link tag for your new print.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/css/print.css" 
type="text/css" media="print"/>
```

In print.css

```
@media print {
    body, html, #wrapper {
     width: 100%;
    }
   div {
     overflow: visible !important;      
    }

}
```

Add a button for Print in your view page.

```
function printPreview() {
  var headerElements = document.getElementsByClassName('fc-header');//.style.display = 'none';
  for(var i = 0, length = headerElements.length; i < length; i++) {
    headerElements[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  var toPrint = document.getElementById('printScheduleArea').cloneNode(true);

  for(var i = 0, length = headerElements.length; i < length; i++) {
        headerElements[i].style.display = '';
  }

  var linkElements = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
  var link = '';
  for(var i = 0, length = linkElements.length; i < length; i++) {
    link = link + linkElements[i].outerHTML;
  }

  var styleElements = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
  var styles = '';
  for(var i = 0, length = styleElements.length; i < length; i++) {
    styles = styles + styleElements[i].innerHTML;
   }

  var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank');
  popupWin.document.open();
  popupWin.document.write('<html><title>Schedule Preview</title>'+link
 +'<style>'+styles+'</style></head><body">')
  popupWin.document.write(toPrint.innerHTML);
  popupWin.document.write('</html>');
  popupWin.document.close();

  setTimeout(popupWin.print(), 20000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Required Js Files

```
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.13.3/exporting/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
   
  /*print*/

    <script>
        $("#print_calendar").click(function () {
        
            html2canvas(document.getElementById("calendar")).then(function (canvas) {
            
            //for give white BG
            var context  = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.save();
            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
            context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.restore();
            
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',1);
            
            //for Save as Image
            /*
            downloadImage(imgData, 'my-canvas.jpeg');
            return; 
            */

            //var doc = new jsPDF();
            var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
            doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10,180, 297);
            download(doc.output(), "calendar.pdf", "text/pdf");
            
        });
    });
    // Save As Image
    function downloadImage(data, filename = 'untitled.jpeg') {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = data;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    }
    
    //Save As PDF (Using jsPDF)
    function download(strData, strFileName, strMimeType) {
        var D = document,
            A = arguments,
            a = D.createElement("a"),
            d = A[0],
            n = A[1],
            t = A[2] || "text/plain";

        //build download link:
        a.href = "data:" + strMimeType + "," + escape(strData);

        if (window.MSBlobBuilder) {
            var bb = new MSBlobBuilder();
            bb.append(strData);
            return navigator.msSaveBlob(bb, strFileName);
        } /* end if(window.MSBlobBuilder) */

        if ('download' in a) {
            a.setAttribute("download", n);
            a.innerHTML = "downloading...";
            D.body.appendChild(a);
            setTimeout(function() {
                var e = D.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                e.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false,
                    false, false, 0, null);
                a.dispatchEvent(e);
                D.body.removeChild(a);
            }, 66);
            return true;
        } /* end if('download' in a) */

        //do iframe dataURL download:
        var f = D.createElement("iframe");
        D.body.appendChild(f);
        f.src = "data:" + (A[2] ? A[2] : "application/octet-stream") + (window.btoa ? ";base64"
            : "") + "," + (window.btoa ? window.btoa : escape)(strData);
        setTimeout(function() {
            D.body.removeChild(f);
        }, 333);
        return true;
    } 
    </script>
    /*print*/
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your html code

```
<div class="" id="component1">
      <full-calendar></full-calendar>
    </div>
```

add print button and pass the id into method

```
<button (click)="printComponent('component1')">Print</button>
```

--

```
printComponent(cmpName) {
        var docHead = document.head.outerHTML;
        var printContents = document.getElementById('component1').outerHTML;
        var winAttr = "location=yes, statusbar=no, menubar=no, titlebar=no, toolbar=no,dependent=no, width=865, height=600, resizable=yes, screenX=200, screenY=200, personalbar=no, scrollbars=yes";
    
        var newWin = window.open("", "_blank", winAttr);
        var writeDoc = newWin.document;
        writeDoc.open();
        writeDoc.write('<!doctype html><html> <style>.fc-header-toolbar{display :none !important;} .fc-scroller.fc-scroller-liquid{overflow:visible !important;} .fc-view-harness.fc-view-harness-active{height:auto !important;}</style>' + docHead + '<body onLoad="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
        writeDoc.close();
        newWin.focus();
      }
```

using this you can take a print of calendar